# Gun shooting on unity5

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

Error:

```
Failed to call function WeaponFire of class gunScript
Calling function WeaponFire with no parameters but the function requires 1.
UnityEngine.Component:SendMessage(String)
weaponController:Update() (at Assets/Fps scripts/weaponController.cs:12)
```

Here's the script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

//This script instantiates a bullet.
public class gunScript : MonoBehaviour {
  public Transform bullet;

  //Called by playerStatus script
  //Instantiates a bullet which is passed in the arguments from PlayerStatus
  void WeaponFire(Transform bullet)
  {
    Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);
  }
}
```

I cant make the gun fire the bullets.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the calling code as well. According to the error message, you are calling the method WeaponFire without an argument.

Good: WeaponFire(bullet)

Bad: WeaponFire()

Answer (score -1):

remove the bullet transform from the function, its already public
your bullet is being instantiated from an existing object,
your script should take the players weapons position and rotation when being instantiated

make sure bullet is set via the inspector.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

//This script instantiates a bullet.
public class gunScript : MonoBehaviour {
  public Transform bullet;

  //Called by playerStatus script
  //Instantiates a bullet which is passed in the arguments from PlayerStatus
  void WeaponFire() 
  {
    Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);
  }
}
```